# Automatic promotion of arithmetic operations

Tags: c++, integer-promotion

Please see the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>
int main()
{
    using T = short;
    auto x = T(1) + T(1);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), T>);
}
```

It seems that the above `static_assert` fails for all of gcc, clang, and msvc and I can't see why. The assertion still fails if I change `short` into any of `bool`, `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, and `unsigned short`, because for all of those cases `decltype(x)` is deduced to be `int`.

Is this the correct behavior given what's explained in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic?

Comment: The page for integral promotion explains that `short` is promoted to `int`.

Comment: This may be a better link: [Integral promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion). Both operands are promoted at least to `int` (or to a bigger type or to floating point type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this promotion from `short` to `int` is required.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic:

> If the operand passed to an arithmetic operator is integral or unscoped enumeration type, then before any other action (but after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable), the operand undergoes integral promotion.

And from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion (emphasis mine):

> prvalues of small integral types (such as char) may be converted to prvalues of larger integral types (such as int). In particular, arithmetic operators *do not accept types smaller than int* as arguments, and *integral promotions are automatically applied* after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable.

and finally:

> signed char or signed short can be converted to int;